# how to interpret temperature value from byte array

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, reverse-engineering

I am doing reverse engineering to Walnut Health thermometer. I am able to get raw data, which is for 97.7 Fahrenheit. It is exactly like that.

```
    DATA: [85, 1, 109, 1, 88, 0, 114, 11, 6, 18] 
    DATA: [85, 1, 109, 1, 88, 0, 114, 11, 6, 18] 
    DATA: [85, 1, 109, 1, 88, 0, 114, 11, 6, 18] 
    DATA: [85, 1, 109, 1, 88, 0, 114, 11, 6, 18]
    DATA: [85, 1, 109, 1, 88, 0, 114, 11, 6, 18]
    DATA: [86, 1, 109, 1, 88, 0, 114, 11, 6, 18]
```

FOR 92.5 Fahrenheit it is

```
    DATA: [78, 1, 78, 1, 83, 0, 84, 11, 6, 18] 
    DATA: [79, 1, 79, 1, 83, 0, 84, 11, 6, 18] 
    DATA: [79, 1, 79, 1, 83, 0, 84, 11, 6, 18] 
    DATA: [79, 1, 79, 1, 83, 0, 84, 11, 6, 18]
    DATA: [79, 1, 79, 1, 83, 0, 84, 11, 6, 18] 
    DATA: [78, 1, 78, 1, 83, 0, 84, 11, 6, 18] 
    DATA: [78, 1, 78, 1, 83, 0, 84, 11, 6, 18] 
    DATA: [78, 1, 78, 1, 83, 0, 84, 11, 6, 18]
    DATA: [78, 1, 78, 1, 83, 0, 84, 11, 6, 18] 
    DATA: [78, 1, 78, 1, 83, 0, 84, 11, 6, 18]
```

I measured Temperature value from its own app so it is not exactly 92.5 its around that value

My question is; how can I interpret temperature value from byte array?

Comment: It would be useful if you could update the question with the UUID of the characteristic. This can be found with a BLE scanning and exploration tool (e.g. [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)) to report what UUIDs are used for the characteristics. This will help identify if it is part of the Bluetooth standard or a [custom characteristic](https://novelbits.io/uuid-for-custom-services-and-characteristics/). If it is standard it will be described in https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/gatt-specification-supplement-6/

Comment: The first two values in `data`. e.g. `[85, 1]` if converted to an integer assuming little endian format gives `341`. Divide that by 10 gives you `34.1`. If we assume that is temperature in Celsius then the formula `(c_value * 9/5) + 32` would give `93.4` Fahrenheit. The next two values in `data` look like they might be a temperature reading also. What programming language are you doing this in?

Answer (score 0):

In Java,

```
 int result = ((data[3] & 0xFF) << 8) | (data[2] & 0xFF);

 float celsius = (float) result / 10;
 float fahrenheit = celsius *9/5 + 32;
```

This code worked for me.